# how to replace keras embedding with pre-trained word embedding to CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, word-embedding

I am currently studying how CNNs can be used in text classification and found some code on stack overflow that had worked with the use of a keras embedding layer.

I ran the code with the keras embedding but now want to test out what would happen with a pre-trained embedding, I have downloaded the word2vec api from gensim but dont know how to adapt the code from there?

My question is how can I replace the keras embedding layer with a pre-trained embedding like the word2vec model or Glove?

heres is the code

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM, Convolution1D, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

# Using keras to load the dataset with the top_words
top_words = 10000
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=top_words)

# Pad the sequence to the same length
max_review_length = 1600
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_review_length)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_review_length)

# Using embedding from Keras
embedding_vecor_length = 300
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_length))

# Convolutional model (3x conv, flatten, 2x dense)
model.add(Convolution1D(64, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Convolution1D(32, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Convolution1D(16, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(180,activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

# Log to tensorboard
tensorBoardCallback = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', write_graph=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, callbacks=[tensorBoardCallback], batch_size=64)

# Evaluation on the test set
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reads the text file containing the weights, stores the words and their weights in a dictionary, then maps them into a new matrix using the vocabulary of your fit tokenizer.

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM, Convolution1D, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow import keras
import itertools
import numpy as np


# Using keras to load the dataset with the top_words
top_words = 10000
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=top_words)

word_index = keras.datasets.imdb.get_word_index()

embedding_vecor_length = 300  # same as the embeds to be loaded below
embeddings_dictionary = dict()
glove_file = open('./embeds/glove.6B.300d.txt', 'rb')

for line in glove_file:
    records = line.split()  # seperates each line by a white space
    word = records[0]  # the first element is the word
    vector_dimensions = np.asarray(
        records[1:], dtype='float32')  # the rest are the weights
    # storing in dictionary
    embeddings_dictionary[word] = vector_dimensions
    
glove_file.close()

# len_of_vocab = len(word_index)
embeddings_matrix = np.zeros((top_words, embedding_vecor_length))
# mapping to a new matrix, using only the words in your tokenizer's vocabulary
for word, index in word_index.items():
    if index>=top_words:
        continue
    # the weights of the individual words in your vocabulary
    embedding_vector = embeddings_dictionary.get(bytes(word, 'utf-8'))
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embeddings_matrix[index] = embedding_vector

# Pad the sequence to the same length
max_review_length = 1600
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_review_length)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_review_length)


# Using embedding from Keras
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length,
          input_length=max_review_length, name="embeddinglayer", weights=[embeddings_matrix], trainable=True))


# Convolutional model (3x conv, flatten, 2x dense)
model.add(Convolution1D(64, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Convolution1D(32, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Convolution1D(16, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(180, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Log to tensorboard
tensorBoardCallback = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', write_graph=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, callbacks=[
          tensorBoardCallback], batch_size=64)


# Evaluation on the test set
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

Comment: Thanks for this have you tried this with a deep learning model before?

Comment: Hi, I just tried it and realised, the words were of bytes type. So, I've edited my answer to reflect on that. It works now.

Comment: hi does code you've added change the performance or just output the embeddings? I have used your original code and seems to work with the model but is  now giving me 50% accuracy on all epochs??

Comment: The last snippet only outputs the embeddings after you have transferred them to the embedding layer, I have changed the first two snippets, copy them again. In the previous one all the weights ended up being 0, because it could not access the weights from the dictionary. That is why you were getting 50% on all epochs. Copy the first two code snippets again, the last snippet is for if you want to see the embeddings after they have been transferred. I used it to debug it, thought I would leave it, it is not necessary.

Comment: thanks but I copied your  code  straight and its not working, im getting an 'InvalidArgumentError:  indices[63,0] = 0 is not in [0, 0)'???, I tried adding one to the the 'len_vocab' after seeing similar problems online but that also did not work. Is there anything else im missing ?

Comment: Its probably because of the word index, I load the same data but from a csv file and use a tokenizer to convert text to sequences and access the word index from that and it works. You can try to do it that way too if you would like, I will try to load the data your way when I am back on my pc.

Comment: yes, how hard would it be to do it my way? because im not sure how you've done it with a csv file.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I have tried it your way and it seems to be working, definitely setting the weights. Not particularly better though, with the loaded embeddings I got 94% train, 84% test accuracy, with randomly generated embeds I got 98% to 85% with much lower loss.

Comment: yh works really well thanks , how does the randomly generated embedding work btw?

Comment: When you do not specify the weights yourself, they are randomly initialized. Since they are trainable parameters they change during training to reduce the loss function, if the trainable is set to True of course which is by default.